# How should I deal with linebreaks in strings I want to marshal in Java to XML?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

How should I deal with linebreaks in strings I want to marshal to XML?

I am having difficulty using Java and JAXB to handle putting strings in XML files that have linefeeds in them. The data is being pulled from a database with the actual line feed characters in them.

```
Foo <LF>
bar
```

Or an additional example:

```
Foo\r\n\r\nBar
```

Yields:

```
Foo&#xD;
&#xD;
Bar
```

If I just marshal this data into XML, I get literal line feed characters in the output. This is apparently against XML standards where the characters should be encoded to `&#xD;`. Ie in the XML file output I should see:

`Foo &#xD;bar`

But if I try and do this manually, I end up with my ampersand getting encoded!

`Foo &amp;#xD;bar`

This is pretty ironic because the process which is apparently supposed to encode the linebreaks in the first place and is not, is foiling my attempts to encode it manually.

Comment: You need to tell us how you are writing the XML file, you are clearly using some mechanism that is translating special characters, and the way you insert special characters will be dependent on that mechanism. It's an important detail, otherwise I'd just tell you that fileWriter.write("&#xD;") works just fine.

Comment: OK, the code is writing XML using `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller`. I create a schema and then compile it using `xjc.exe`. Hopefully this is enough info?

Comment: Literal new lines are fine in _element_ content, and in attributes the marshaller should automatically encode them as `&#10;` where necessary, so it should just work as it is.

Comment: Interesting @IanRoberts... I inherited this software and they had implemented this procedure to convert literal LF characters into just the string `#xA`... mind you, it's pretty inconsistent about when and where it does it, but now I'm co-operating with an external developer into making sure both our tools maintain data integrity. Should I leave literal line feeds in element content the same then? I've even seen others suggesting to replace with `\n`. Perhaps you can reference us to the standard indicating it's OK to use literal new lines in element content. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Below is an example of JAXB's default behaviour regarding `\n` and `\r`:

**Java Model (Root)**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private String foo;
    private String bar;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo Code**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.setFoo("Hello\rWorld");
        root.setBar("Hello\nWorld");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><root><bar>Hello
World</bar><foo>Hello&#xD;World</foo></root>
```

---

### UPDATE

Below are some additional details based on some investigation that I did.

**Common to All [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) Implementations**

- If you are marshalling to an `XMLStreamWriter` or `XMLEventWriter` directly (via `Marshaller`) or indirectly (via potentially a JAX-RS or JAX-WS provider) then the escaping will be based on the StAX implementation.  Woodstox appears to escape things correctly, but the StAX implementation in the JDK I'm using did not.

**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

- There is a bug in MOXy related to escaping `\r` that I am currently in the process of fixing (see: http://bugs.eclipse.org/414608)

**JAXB Reference Implementation**

- The JAXB reference implementation will properly escape '\r' when marshalling to an `OutputStream`, but not to a `Writer` atleast in the JDK I'm using.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have gone through the code and found some changes to the default Marshaller object - namely, we call `setSchema`, set `JAXB_FRAGMENT` to true and `JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` to true. Could any of these result in the literal line breaks being returned? Or is your output there implying that literal line breaks in the XML output are the result of handling `\r`?

Comment: @deed02392 - I have updated my answer with the results of my investigation into this issue.

Comment: This is great. In my case I'm marshalling directly to a `FileOutputStream`. My input string has `Foo\r\n\r\nBar` and I end up with `Foo&#xD;(NL)
&#xD;(NL)
Bar`. Is that correct, then? I thought I understood that XML should reduce `\r\n` sequences to a single `\n` and encode that.